# d3 custom scale, linear(x), draw start and end

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to draw a rectangle from a given start location to an end location with a custom scale.
If the data starts at 0 and ends at X everything works as expected.

But if the data starts at X and ends at Y (which is greater than X) the value does not end at Y because of the d3 linear() function (see at FIXME). 
How can I achieve this behaviour?

[image]

**Description:**
Data starts at 250 and does not end at 500 (250+250) but at 1k. The same goes to the one that starts at 150 and does not end at 500 (150+350) but at around 750.

Here my code:

```
var w = 400;
var h = 175;
var padding = 30;
var groups = [];
groups.push([0, 0, 1000, 30], [0, 0, 6000, 30], [150, 0, 350, 30], [250, 0, 250, 30]);

// Your custom scale:
var scale = [0,125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,6000];
var output = [0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350];
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(scale)
    .range(output);

// The axis uses the above scale and the same domain:
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(scale)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

var svg = d3.select(element)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

//Create X axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+"," + (h - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);


//Drawing data
svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "groups")
    .selectAll("groups")
    .data(groups)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0])+padding;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * d[3];
    })

    //FIXME: something different must be done here.
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[2]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d[3];
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the correct width by subtracting the start position from the end position:

```
.attr("width", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0] + d[2]) - xScale(d[0]) - padding;
})
```